# When someone click option of last question there is error in the console. How can I avoid it

Tags: javascript, arrays, events

I am making a quiz webpage. **Whenever option of last question is clicked I get error in the console. It says "cannot read properties of undefined". Because it exceeds the length of the quesAns object.**
see my code

```
const question = document.querySelector(".ques");
const first = document.querySelector(".first");
const second = document.querySelector(".second");
const third = document.querySelector(".third");
const fourth = document.querySelector(".fourth");
const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".ans");
const rightAnswer = document.querySelector(".right_ans");

let seq = 0;
let seq2 = -1;

const quesAns = [
  {
    ques: "Who is the CEO of Google?",
    a: "A. Bill Gates",
    b: "B. Tim Cook",
    c: "C. Sundar Pichai",
    d: "D. Larry Page",
    true: "C. Sundar Pichai",
  },
  {
    ques: "Who is founder of Microsoft",
    a: "A. Elon Musk",
    b: "B. Steve Jobs",
    c: "C. Mark Jukerberg",
    d: "D. Bill Gates",
    true: "D. Bill Gates",
  },
  {
    ques: "Who is founder of Facebook?",
    a: "A. Mark Zukerberg",
    b: "B. Larry Page",
    c: "C. Satya Nadela",
    d: "D. Evan Spiegel",
    true: "A. Mark Zukerberg",
  },
  {
    ques: "Who is richest person in the world?",
    a: "A. Mark Zukerberg",
    b: "B. Elon Musk",
    c: "C. Bill gates",
    d: "D. Mukesh Ambani",
    true: "B. Elon Musk",
  },
  {
    ques: "What is responsible for styling in web page?",
    a: "HTML",
    b: "XML",
    c: "CSS",
    d: "JavaScript",
    true: "CSS",
  }
];

function moreQA() {
  question.innerHTML = quesAns[seq].ques;
  first.innerHTML = quesAns[seq].a;
  second.innerHTML = quesAns[seq].b;
  third.innerHTML = quesAns[seq].c;
  fourth.innerHTML = quesAns[seq].d;
}

answers.forEach((ans) => {
  ans.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    seq++;
    seq2++;
    if (quesAns[seq2].true == e.target.innerHTML.trim()) {
      rightAnswer.innerHTML = "Your answer is right";
      rightAnswer.style.color = "green";
    } else {
      rightAnswer.innerHTML = "Your answer is wrong";
      rightAnswer.style.color = "red";
    }
    moreQA();
  });
});
```

And I don't want to repeat the question again from starting. Please tell me how can I avoid that error.

Comment: Make `moreQA` check whether there are any more questions/answers.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - you can simplify this by delegating and using data-attributes and a few ternaries

Comment: Also this is easier to test `{
    ques: "What is responsible for styling in web page?",
    a: "HTML",
    b: "XML",
    c: "CSS",
    d: "JavaScript",
    correct: "c",
  }`

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks that naming a variable 'true' is a very bad thing?

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to load more questions that's why you're getting this error. you should check if there are more questions available before loading it

```
function moreQA() 
  {
  if(quesAns.length >= seq) return;

  question.innerHTML = quesAns[seq].ques;
  first   .innerHTML = quesAns[seq].a;
  second  .innerHTML = quesAns[seq].b;
  third   .innerHTML = quesAns[seq].c;
  fourth  .innerHTML = quesAns[seq].d;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that is easier to add questions to

It just needs the object and it will create the questions. The next button will be disabled at the end of the questions so you will not have the problem of exceeding the length of the array

It uses delegation to see which button was clicked and uses the label to show correct or not

```js
let cnt = 0;
const questions = document.getElementById("questions");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const next = document.getElementById("next");
const ask = () => {
  result.innerHTML = ``;
  next.disabled = cnt>=quesAns.length-1;

  if (cnt >= quesAns.length) {
    return;
  }  
  const curr = quesAns[cnt];
  const correct = curr.correct;
  questions.innerHTML = `<h3>${curr.ques}</h3>`;
  //  console.log( Object.entries(curr))
  questions.innerHTML += Object.entries(curr).map(([key, value]) => ['ques', 'correct'].includes(key) ? '' : `<label data-val="${key}" data-correct="${correct === key}"><input type="radio" name="answer" />${key.toUpperCase()}: ${value}</label>`).join('<br/>');
  cnt++;
};
questions.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("label");
  if (!tgt) return; // not an input
  const correct = tgt.dataset.correct === "true";
  questions.querySelectorAll("label").forEach(label => { // reset
    label.classList.toggle("correct", false);
    label.classList.toggle("incorrect", false);
  })
  tgt.classList.toggle("correct", correct);
  tgt.classList.toggle("incorrect", !correct);
  result.innerHTML = `Your answer is ${correct ? "correct" : "incorrect"}`;
});
next.addEventListener("click", ask);
ask();
```

```css
.incorrect {
  color: red
}

.correct {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="questions"></div>
<span id="result"></span>
<hr/>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>

<script>
  const quesAns = [{
      ques: "Who is the CEO of Google?",
      a: "Bill Gates",
      b: "Tim Cook",
      c: "Sundar Pichai",
      d: "Larry Page",
      correct: "c"
    },
    {
      ques: "Who is founder of Microsoft",
      a: "Elon Musk",
      b: "Steve Jobs",
      c: "Mark Jukerberg",
      d: "Bill Gates",
      correct: "d"
    },
    {
      ques: "Who is founder of Facebook?",
      a: "Mark Zukerberg",
      b: "Larry Page",
      c: "Satya Nadela",
      d: "Evan Spiegel",
      correct: "a"
    },
    {
      ques: "Who is richest person in the world?",
      a: "Mark Zukerberg",
      b: "Elon Musk",
      c: "Bill gates",
      d: "Mukesh Ambani",
      correct: "b"
    },
    {
      ques: "What is responsible for styling in web page?",
      a: "HTML",
      b: "XML",
      c: "CSS",
      d: "JavaScript",
      correct: "c"
    }
  ];
</script>
```